# IBM Data Science Experience (DSX): Decision Optimization in DSX

Tags: data-science-experience, docplexcloud

Thanks in advance.

I'm using IBM Data Science Experience (DSX). In order to use Decision Optimization in DSX, I need to get a DOcplexcloud API Key.

How to get the API Key?

Once again, thank you very much for the time you've given.

Regards,

Deb

Answer (score 0):

You need to either need to have a Docplex Cloud Website account
https://dropsolve-oaas.docloud.ibmcloud.com/software/analytics/docloud
and follow this document to get the API Key.
https://developer.ibm.com/docloud/documentation/decision-optimization-on-cloud/api-key/

or
You can provision Decision Optimization Instance on bluemix
https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/decision-optimization?env_id=ibm%3Ayp%3Aus-south

`{
  "url": "https://api-oaas.docloud.ibmcloud.com/job_manager/rest/v1",
  "client_id": "bm_api_ext_4ea008b2-687d-4ce4-8b0a-712f0ed680e1",
  "subscriptionId": "bm_45b16939-2382-4f6f-a2d2-c9ae5aae87c1"
}`

When you using it on DSX, 
With Python API,(https://developer.ibm.com/docloud/documentation/docloud/python-api/python-example/)

use url for BaseURL
and client_id is API Key.

https://developer.ibm.com/docloud/documentation/docloud/rest-api/rest-api-example/

Here is the whole notebook:-
https://github.com/charles2588/bluemixsparknotebooks/blob/master/Python/docplex.ipynb